# I don't want it to return the _id of the database

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am creating a login page and if the person successfully logs in it returns the user information from the database, but I would like it not to return the `_id` that the database allocates, someone knows how to do it.

Function code

```js
function userSearch(req, res) {
    const user = req.params.userId
    console.log(user)
    User.findOne({ user }, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send({
                message: 'A ocurrido un error ' + err + '',
                status: 500
            })
        } else if (!user) {
            res.status(404).send({
                message: 'No se a encontrado al usuario'
            })
        } else {
            res.status(200).send({
                user
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`$projection`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) to return only values you want.

Is only add a new object in the query where you says: `{_id: 0}`.

Like this:

```
db.collection.find({},
{
  _id: 0,
})
```

Check [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yXtGYrcchW2) where I've not displayed `_id` and `field2`.

So in your case will be something like:

```js
User.findOne({user}, {_id:0}, (err, user) =>{
   //...
})
```

Also, if you don't want to return another field as password or something like this, you  only have to add into `projection`.

```js
User.findOne({user}, {_id:0, pass:0}, (err, user) =>{
   //...
})
```

And so on, how many fields as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a copy of your object and them remove it with `delete`.

```js
User.findOne({user}, (err, user) =>{
    if(err){
        res.status(500).send({message: 'A ocurrido un error '+err+'', status: 500})
    }else if(!user){
        res.status(404).send({message: 'No se a encontrado al usuario'})
    }else{
        const copyOfUser = {...user};
        delete copyOfUser._id;
        res.status(200).send({user: copyOfUser})
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the field from a document by setting the value `_id: 0` after the search parameters

```
function userSearch(req, res) {
    const user = req.params.userId
    console.log(user)
    User.findOne({ user }, {_id: 0}, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send({
                message: 'A ocurrido un error ' + err + '',
                status: 500
            })
        } else if (!user) {
            res.status(404).send({
                message: 'No se a encontrado al usuario'
            })
        } else {
            res.status(200).send({
                user
            })
        }
    })
}
```